# Reading a XML file from JAR within web application

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to read XML file from JAR used as library in my web app. How can I achieve that? My directory structure for XML file is:

```
commons/resources/config.xml
```

where `commons` is a Java project for which I will create a JAR and place under

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/myWebApp-1.4/WEB-INF/lib
```

after building and deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the XML file as resource from classpath this way: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml")`. It returns a stream that you can use for reading the content of the file and do with it whatever you want. It is only possible within the webapp the jar belongs to because webapps are isolated with respect to classloading.

Comment: Which class name I have to give and what classpath needs to be given?

Comment: You don't have to choose a class name and the classpath is probably set by Tomcat.